# How can I bind a onclick event to a checkbox INSTEAD of a change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here is the problem I have.

I'm making a control panel for some devices. Now the user can enable/toggle an on/off switch (checkbox) and so can a remote device. This is reflected in the database.
However, I also want a confirm box whenever the user (NOT the device) toggles to enable the device (checkbox == checked). No confirmation box required for when the user disables (toggles off, checkbox==false) the device.
I check the database every few seconds to see the state of device (since the device can turn itself on or off)

This is what I have so far (It doesn't work correctly. Nothing is sent to the database. on click doeesn't fire on user click in checkbox)

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle').bootstrapToggle({
      on: TR_Toggle_On,
      off: TR_Toggle_Off
    });
    check_enable();

    function check_enable() {
        var timer = setInterval(function(result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "checkState.php",
                success: function(result) {
                    var enabled =parseInt(result);
                    if (enabled ===1) {
                        $( '#toggle').bootstrapToggle('on');
                    } else {
                        $( '#toggle').bootstrapToggle('off');
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    }

    $('#toggle').on('click',function(){
        $('#toggle').change(function() {
            if ($('#toggle').prop('checked') ===true) {
                if(confirm("Sure?")){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "setEnable.php",
                    data: "enable=1"
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#toggle').prop('checked',false);
                }
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "setEnable.php",
                    data: "enable=0"
                });
            }
        })
    })


})
```

How can I do this? When I try to register the on('click',func(){}) event, nothing fires. I assume it doesn't work for checkboxes? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding an event within another event..

```
$('#toggle').on('click',function(){
    $('#toggle').change(function() {
    ...
    }
}
```

You should only bind once, like this...

```
    $('#toggle').on('click',function(){
        if ($('#toggle').prop('checked') ===true) {
            if(confirm("Sure?")){
                $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "setEnable.php",
                data: "enable=1"
                });
            }else{
                $('#toggle').prop('checked',false);
            }
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "setEnable.php",
                data: "enable=0"
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works for checkboxes.

Tried a minimal example like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="dog" value="TinyDog" /> what does the dog say

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.toggle').on('click',function(){
  alert("woff woff");
  }); 
});
```

Try adding some console.log lines or alerts to see where your code fails.